# My Azure function url says 'segments' instead of my function name

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

I have a function app hosted on azure when I get the url endpoint of the function it says https://my_function_app.azurewebsites.net/api/{*segments} instead of https://my_function_app.azurewebsites.net/api/function_name. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have set route template.

If you create function on portal, click `Integrate` blade and delete values in `Route template`.

If you deploy pre-complied function to Azure, you should remove this setting in your code.

For c#, set `Route=null` in `HttpTrigger` attribute in your .cs file. For js, remove `route` parameter in `function.json` file.

Comment: Got it yes, I'd installed a npm module that set a route parameter in my function.json file